Why does my IOPS keep increasing during bulk batch inserts?
The database in question: AWS RDS, MySQL 8, InnoDB. GP3 storage.
I am attempting to do a bulk insert of rows to multiple tables in the db.
I have omitted all secondary indexes from the target table, it has only PK. The target table is not partitioned.
The source data for the import (which is not in MySQL) is partitioned by date range. For each partition I have a script which selects a batch of data and inserts it to MySQL. The per-partition batch loop scripts are running simultaneously in parallel.
Each batch is loaded as a pandas dataframe per table, various transformations are done, and then the dataframes for the batch are inserted to MySQL (in one db transaction) using pandas to_sql "multi" insert method.
I can think of various ways to improve this. Two suggestions that come up in all MySQL bulk insert advice are to a) insert in PK order and b) use LOAD DATA IN FILE. I'm currently doing neither. But before I radically rewrite all the code I would like to understand the symptom I am seeing when I run the current code:

We can see the import running for ~1hr. The number of parallel batch scripts is consistent throughout. The batch size is consistent throughout. Each batch takes ~60s to process and insert. In graph above ~200 batches (several million rows) are processed successfully. But the IOPS increases roughly linearly for 30 mins until it hits the provisioned limit and gets throttled.
My question is: if my insert rate is constant, why does the IOPS keep increasing linearly?

"I have a script which selects a batch of data and inserts it to MySQL" how these batch selects are happening , using offset or keyset ? Also in dataframe.to_sql what is the value of chunksize parameter if it is being used ?
chunksize int, optional: Specify the number of rows in each batch to be written at a time. By default, all rows will be written at once.

@ShivamKumar The batch selects are against a different database server. I'm really looking for insight into the symptom rather than advice on my script. I am using a large chunk size, but this doesn't change while executing... my question is about why the IOPS continue ramping up while the scripts are already running a long time.

I was thinking if the selects are using offset method to select data in batch may be its happening because as its moving down the table its pulling rows into memory which are not required only to discard them later, I can be wrong, output from SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS can give you more details to look, good luck.

@ShivamKumar the selects are happening on a different database, loaded into memory as pandas dataframe, then inserted to mysql. So it's only the inserts that are relevant here

ok may be information from this link from aws can be an explanation which says :
"When small I/O operations are physically sequential, Amazon EBS attempts to merge them into a single I/O operation up to the maximum I/O size. Similarly, when I/O operations are larger than the maximum I/O size, Amazon EBS attempts to split them into smaller I/O operations. " Example table on link explains this further.

@ShivamKumar why would that cause continually increasing amount of IOPS over time?

You might want to read this part of the [link] (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ebs/latest/userguide/ebs-io-characteristics.html#ebs-io-size-throughput-limits)

@ShivamKumar thanks that's interesting info! I think the first paragraph describes a care where system is unable to reach provisioned IOPS limit (not my problem, I hit 3000 limit after a while) and second para describes case where system reports IOPS going higher than the limit (not my case, I can see it plateau at the 3000 limit). I am looking for the reason my IOPS increases linearly over period of 30 mins of roughly constant load.

"The per-partition batch loop scripts are running simultaneously in parallel." -- I/O is a limiting factor as you have discovered.

Are the rows in PK- order when handed to MySQL?  Are you doing LOAD DATA or bulk insert?

"selects are happening on a different database" -- Those would show up as reads.  And if you have an ORDER BY, that could be a lot of reading and even some writing (temp table for sorting).

Can you get rid of Pandas and simply do INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ...?

"continually increasing amount of IOPS over time" -- That smacks of random access, either on reading or writing.  You simply have not provided enough details fo say.

I had a hypothesis for this before asking the question, but there were also a lot of other things that could have been going on that I maybe don't know about.
In the end I got around to testing my hypothesis and it seems to have been correct.
As mentioned in the question, all secondary indexes (and unique & foreign key constraints) had been omitted from the table. But primary key was left in place.
The reason for keeping the PK was I had read some advice that adding PK after the import would be very expensive, because it has to rebuild the whole table due to being "clustered" index.
I had done some tests on my local machine with smaller data (~250k rows) and observed that it was slower to omit the PK + add it after than it was to just insert with the PK still in place.
However when running the full-size import and observing the ever-increasing IOPS I guessed that this could be due to how we were inserting rows in parallel, making it impossible for inserts to arrive in strict PK order. The hypothesis was that every commit of a batch of rows had to reshuffle the PK index, so as the size of index grew the amount of work per commit grew linearly.
So I re-ran the import with PK removed from the CREATE TABLE and saw this:

...nice flat graphs, well below the IOPS limit.
So I've got all the data in there now and I "just" have to add the necessary indexes back in.
